# Pymongo connect to mongodb with Authentificate error

Tags: python, pymongo

Good day!

I try to connect to mongodb and execute the script.
Tried to do it through python and pymongo. It seems that something good is going on, but in the end it throws errors.

In javascript is all good.
Here is what I have in javascript

```
mongo -u MYUSER -p MYPASSWD 127.0.0.1:27017/MYDB --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
```

and I see result

But with python not so good
Here is what I have in python

```
import pymongo
import bson
import urllib.parse

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 27017
user = "MYUSER"
password = "MYPASSWD"
dbname = "MYDB"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(f'mongodb://"{user}:{urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}?authSource=admin')
#db = client.get_database()
db = client[dbname]
collection_vhs = db['vhs']

result = collection_vhs.find({"idSimple":"/01/"})
for doc in result:
        print(result)
```

Here is the error

```
(env) root@MYHOST:~# python3 /etc/zabbix/scripts/mongodb_field_idSimple.py


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/zabbix/scripts/mongodb_field_idSimple.py", line 21, in <module>
    for doc in result:
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1248, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1165, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1053, in __send_message
    operation, self._unpack_response, address=self.__address
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1272, in _run_operation
    retryable=isinstance(operation, message._Query),
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1365, in _retryable_read
    with self._socket_from_server(read_pref, server, session) as (sock_info, read_pref):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1221, in _socket_from_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1156, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(handler=err_handler) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1379, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket()
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1489, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect()
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1350, in connect
    sock_info.authenticate()
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 845, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(creds, self)
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 549, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 475, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, "SCRAM-SHA-1")
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 201, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 764, in command
    exhaust_allowed=exhaust_allowed,
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 164, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error,
  File "/root/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 180, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

I just don't get it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The double quote in the connection string looks incorrect.

Comment: Yes. Thanx. Rewrote so many times due to an authentication error that I just didn’t notice it already